# Java Regex compress String

Tags: java, regex, string, pattern-matching

I have random String for example `"aaaaaaBccccCCCCd"` I need make regex which searches the text for groups to get effect `"a6B1c4C4d1"`. My regex looks like that `"(\\D+)\\D*\\1"` but he lost single letters, so in this sample `B` and `d`.

Maybe someone would have an idea?

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
public class Compress {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String text = "aaaaaaBccccCCCCd";
        String regex = "(\\D+)\\D*\\1";           // or (.+).*\\1
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
        String result = new String();
        while (matcher.find()) {
            String letter = matcher.group().substring(0, 1);
            String numberOfLetter = String.valueOf(matcher.group().length());
            result = result + letter + numberOfLetter;
        }
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Why `\D`? Are you targeting non-digits only?

Comment: Yes, only non-digits

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following approach based on `Matcher#appendReplacement`:

```
String text = "aaaaaaBccccCCCCd"; //a6B1c4C4d1
String regex = "(.)(\\1*)"; 
String pattern = "test";
Pattern r = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher m = r.matcher(text);
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
while (m.find()) {
    m.appendReplacement(sb, m.group(1) + (m.group(2).length()+1));
}
m.appendTail(sb);
System.out.println(sb);
```

See the [Java demo](http://ideone.com/xqnVSf)

The `(.)(\1*)` will capture any char into Group 1 and then will capture into Group 2 zero or more repetitions of the same content. In the "callback", Group 1 is concatenated with the length of Group 2 incremented to account for the Group 1 length.

Comment: Great. Thank you very much!